# What's the configuration file name for Emacs ansi-term?

Tags: emacs

I tried to create a .emacs-bash file and that works for `M-x shell`.  But if I use the ansi-term, it appears that the .emacs-bash file is not loaded...  How can I solve this?

I used `M-x ansi-term` and then `\bin\bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `~/.emacs_SHELLNAME` (or `~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh`) behaviour is special to the `shell` function (which, naturally, knows that you're going to be running a shell).

`ansi-term` is a terminal emulator. It doesn't know what kind of process you're going to be running with it, so it doesn't attempt to apply any custom config files.

If you run a shell in the terminal, that shell should apply its normal rules for config files, so I would try `.bashrc` for starters.

Failing that, read the bash man page to see what the rules are. Environment variables would likely come into play (and you could test for environment variables in your .bashrc to provide Emacs-specific behaviour).